# How to pad the required content to a text file

Tags: c#, winforms, string

Hi all i am doing an application where i write my data to the text file. What ever data that user enters on the form and click on save i will save that data to the text file that was chosen by the user . Assume my content is as follows

`1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234
1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234`

I would like to pad the next `8` lines with the following
`9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999`

Lie that if i have `5` lines of text in the file i would like to pad the next 5 lines with the same as mentioned can any one tell how to do this

```
Each and every line length is '94'

Any number of lines can be there
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what if 10 lines are there

Comment: whats your app defined line length? or when should the line break rather?

Comment: If `10` lines i don't need to pad.. Line length is `94`

Comment: Question is unclear, you just added some important details in comment, so please put all those details in question itself and it would be great see example: INPUT data and OUTPUT data, if there different cases - mention all of them

Comment: You should tell us if your user is allowed to enter more than 10 lines and if your file should always be 960 byte in leght (94*10 + 2 chars for newline in each line)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here goes the code.

> 1) Find out the no of lines in your file
>
> 2) make count%10, if count%10==0 do not pad else 10-result=required
>   length , Pad with required length.

Sample code assume you have `8` lines

```
    int cnt = 8; 
    int result = cnt % 10;  // Will get 8
    int iresult1 = 10 - result;
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

```
var text = "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234" + Environment.NewLine + "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234";
const String padWith = "9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999";
const int lineNum = 10;
var lines = text.Split(new[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList();
while(lines.Count < lineNum) {
    lines.Add(padWith);
}
File.WriteAllLines(path, lines);
```